# how to update state variables inside prepareheaders in rtk query

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I start to use RTK query and try to update headers with new access tokens but found it's hard to update the access in `state`. More specifically, there is no way to access `dispatch` inside `prepareHeaders`. Only `getState` is exposed.

```
createApi({
  reducerPath: 'baseApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "/",
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState } ) => {
      const { token, expiration } = getState().auth
      if (expiration > new Date()) {
        if (token) {
          headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
        }
      } else {
        // if token expired, get a new token
        try {
          const result = await fetch("/token_store")
          //dispatch(setNewToken(result)) ---> how to use dispatch here?
        } catch (err) {
          console.log("something goes wrong.")
        }
      }
      return headers
  }),
  endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely not do that in `prepareHeaders` - there is a reason why there is no `dispatch` available there.

For something like that, you would wrap your baseQuery.

There are some examples of wrapping the basequery [here in the documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#automatic-re-authorization-by-extending-fetchbasequery)

Comment: Do you happen to know the reason? I believe it is weird not to include dispatch in prepareheaders. My reason why this is weird is in the case of authentication, I need two functions to simply set/refresh a token.

Comment: Since I've written that code, yes. 
It is the wrong place to do this. 
You are in the middle of making a request here. It's the place where you decide if you want to add a certain header or not. It's not the place to make an api request against your server to get that new token, save it to the store and all that stuff. That should happen either before or after the request, but not in a function called `prepareHeaders`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But isn't fetchBaseQuery/prepareHeaders happening before each endpoint request?

Comment: Technically. But it is not the intended place to do this. The function is called `prepareHeaders`. It has a single purpose and you get the tools to fulfill that single purpose there. If you want to do more than that, we have the documented pattern of wrapping the baseQuery to add side effects before or after the request. It is much more clear for the next person touching the code to do stuff like this there: where it is documented.

Comment: just my 2 cents: it makes things complicated by splitting the same functionality into two places. If there are too many such complexities, people will definitely quit using the tool.

Comment: From my experience supporting users and helping them debug their applications, having one documented place where things *should* be beats having 20 places where things *maybe could* be. But of course your mileage may vary. 