# Set Authorization header in RTK Query with Next Auth

Tags: next.js, next-auth, rtk-query

I am currently using Next Auth to do authorization with Active Directory. I need to use the access token I receive and use it in the Authorization header. The problem is you can't use the useSession hook as it is not a react component. Not sure what kind approach I should take.

Here's where I'm trying to add the token:

```js
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}`,
  prepareHeaders: (headers, {
    getState
  }) => {
    headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
  }
  return headers;
},
});
```

I know token is undefined. Its only there to show where I need it.
I think I need to use redux, but I am not sure how to set the access token if the login happens on the Microsoft SSO page.

I hope this made sense.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73992685/763880) you should be wrapping the baseQuery component and retrieving the token via (I assume) MSAL.

You should not be retrieving it via a hook within `prepareHeaders`.

In order to retrieve the token you would be invoking `acquireTokenSilent()` from the msal instance. More [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-acquire-token)

Answer (score 0):

I personally do it like this ...

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { HYDRATE } from "next-redux-wrapper";

const addTokenToRequest = async (headers: any, { getState }: any) => {
  const session: any = await getSession();
  if (session?.user?.accessToken) {
    headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${session.user.accessToken}`);
  }
  return headers;
};

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: process.env.API_BASE_URL || process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL,

  prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }: any) => {
    return addTokenToRequest(headers, { getState });
  },
});

const baseQueryWithReauth = async (args: any, api: any, extraOptions: any) => {
  let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);

  if (result?.error?.status === 403) {
    // Implement logic for restricted access
  } else if (result?.error?.status === 401) {
    //Logout the user
    //Or redirect to unauthorized page
  } else {
    //Allow the user to access the route.
  }

  return result;
};

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
  extractRehydrationInfo(action, { reducerPath }) {
    if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
      return action.payload[reducerPath];
    }
  },
  endpoints: builder => ({}),
});
```

Comment: I'm getting unhandled error: processing request for endpoint 'getSomeQuery', Error Invalid hook call with this approach.
I'm injecting the endpoints as shown in RTK Query code splitting documentation, but the network doesn't seem to hit the given endpoint.
Can you help me with this one?